# What is the correct way to change the "items per slide" configuration in product carousel from 4 items per slide to 3 items per slide in Spartacus.4

Tags: spartacus-storefront

I tried this -

```
export class CustomProductCarouselComponent extends ProductCarouselComponent {
    constructor(
    componentData: CmsComponentData<model>,
    productService: ProductService
  ) {
    super(componentData, productService);
  }
  getProduct(code: string): Observable<Product> {
    return this.productService.get(code);
  }
}
```

But Html template gives error of type. [see screenshot for the same](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7e0xF.png).

Comment: Regarding the issue in the template - though it's not visible in the given code snippet, it appears you specified your `items$` observable to be of type `Observable<Product[] | null>`, whereas `Observable<Product[]>` is expect (no null allowed). To solve it, type your overridden `items$` array to `Observable<Product[]>` and make sure there are no null values.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can set the attribute `itemWidth` in your html template where you are integrated the carousel tag `<cx-carousel ... itemWidth="33%"...>`

Comment: Please click on link for error screenshot posted above. I am not able to integrate carousel template as it keeps giving error (see error screenshot). Any idea what can be the issue. Thanks.

Comment: Are you extending your `custom-product-carousel` from `ProductCarouselComponent` ?
Put your `cx-carousel`-Tag inside an `ng-container` like so
`<ng-container *ngIf="items$ | async as products"><cx-carousel *ngIf="products.length" [items]="products" [title]="title$ | async" ...></cx-carousel></ng-container>`